# Find and replace all names of variables in VBA module

Tags: vba, obfuscation

Let's assume that we have one module with only one Sub in it, and there are no comments. How to identify all variable names ? Is it possible to identify names of variables which are not defined using `Dim` ? I would like to identify them and replace each with some random name to obfuscate my code (O0011011010100101 for example), replace part is much easier.

List of characters which could be use in names of macros, functions and variables :

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzg€‚„…†‡‰Š‹ŚŤŽŹ‘’“”•–—™š›śťžź ˇ˘Ł¤Ą¦§¨©Ş«¬­®Ż°±˛ł´µ¶·¸ąş»Ľ˝ľżŔÁÂĂÄĹĆÇČÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚŰÜÝŢßŕáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőö÷řůúűüýţ˙ÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚŰÜÝŢßŕáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőö÷řůúűüýţ˙
```

Below are my function I've wrote recenlty :

```
Function randomName(n as integer) as string
   y="O"
   For i = 2 To n:
       If Rnd() > 0.5 Then
          y = y & "0"
       Else
          y = y & "1"
       End If
    Next i

   randomName=y
End Function
```

In goal to replace given strings in another string which represent the code of module I use below sub :

```
Sub substituteNames()
    'count lines in "Module1" which is part of current workbook
    linesCount = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.CountOfLines
    'read code from module
    code = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(StartLine:=1, Count:=linesCount)

    inputStr = Array("name1", "name2", "name2") 'some hardwritten array with string to replace
    namesLength = 20                            'length of new variables names

    For i = LBound(inputStr) To UBound(inputStr)
       outputString = randomName(namesLength-1)
       code = Replace(code, inputStr(i), outputString)
    Next i

    Debug.Print code 'view code
End Sub
```

then we simply substitute old code with new one, but how to identify strings with names of variables ?

**Edition**
Using **Option Explicit ** decrease safety of my simple method of obfuscation, because to reverse changes you only have to follow `Dim` statements and replace ugly names with something normal. Except that to make such substitution harder, I think it's good idea to break the line in the middle of variable name :

```
O0O000O0OO0O0000 _
0O00000O0OO0
```

the simple method is also replacing some strings with chains based on `chr` functions `chr(104)&chr(101)&chr(108)&chr(108)&chr(111)`  :

```
Sub stringIntoChrChain()

    strInput = "hello"
    strOutput = ""

    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strOutput = strOutput & "chr(" & Asc(Mid(strInput, i, 1)) & ")&"
    Next i

    Debug.Print Mid(strOutput, 1, Len(strOutput) - 1)
End Sub
```

comments like below could make impression on user and make him think that he does not poses right tool to deal with macro etc.:

```
'(k=Äó¬)w}ż^¦ů‡ÜOyúm=ěËnóÚŽb W™ÄQó’ (—*-ĹTIäb
'R“ąNPÔKZMţ†üÍQ‡
'y6ű˛Š˛ŁŽ¬=iýQ|˛^˙  ‡ńb ¬ĂÇr'ń‡e˘źäžŇ/âéç;1qýěĂj$&E!V?¶ßšÍ´cĆ$Âű×şŮî’ď˛¦Ŕ?TáÄu[nG¦•¸î»éüĽ˙xVPĚ.|
'ÖĚ/łó®Üă9Ę]ż/ĹÍT¶Mµę¶mÍ
'q[—qëýY~Pc©=jÍ8˘‡,Ú+ń8ŐűŻEüńWü1ďëÇ±†ć}ęńwŠbŢ,>ó’Űçµ™Š_…qÝăt±+‡ĽČg­řÍ!·eŠP âńđ:Ĺ¶OĂˇžű?őë®ÁšńýĎáËTbž}|Ö…ăË[®™
```

Comment: why dont you stick an [**Option Explicit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) at the top of your module? Don't think there is a way to return all variable names without having written some sort of VBA code interpreter..Or use [**THIS**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/invisiblebasic/) or [**THAT**](http://www.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/vbaobfusc) (*havent tried myself*)

Comment: or http://www.tooloscope.com/en/IT-tools/vba-code-obfuscation.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+obfuscate

Comment: Here is [Chip Pearson's method](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/list-of-variables-in-a-module/dc4d1ee8-fbeb-4497-88ed-b94bbdb2803c), but it appears to key on the `Dim` keyword.

Comment: *to obfuscate my code...*  Your successor is going to love you :)

Comment: You need a regexp genius friend. It can be done if you can get a regular expression to return the single word prior to an "=" sign, but isn't preceded with the word IF. I'm just not good enough with them to get a good return.

Comment: @me how Without Dim it it's harder to find variable names

Comment: I updated my answer. The regex is much closer to correct. Let me know if you work out a solution. This might have consumed me today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find variable assignments by looking for the equals sign. You'll need to add a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** and **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3** libraries as I've used early binding.

Please be sure to back up your work and test this before using it. I could have gotten the regex wrong.

**UPDATE:**

I've refined the regular expressions so that it no longer catches datatypes of strongly typed constants (`Const ImAConstant As String = "Oh Noes!"` previously returned `String`). I've also added another regex to return those constants as well. The last version of the regex also mistakenly caught things like `.Global = true`. That was corrected. The code below should return all variable and constant names for a given code module. The regular expressions still aren't perfect, as you'll note that I was unable to stop false positives on double quotes. Also, my array handling could be done better.

```
Sub printVars()
    Dim linesCount As Long
    Dim code As String
    Dim vbPrj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim codeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim m As VBScript_RegExp_55.match
    Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim isInDatatypes As Boolean
    Dim isInVariables As Boolean
    Dim datatypes() As String
    Dim variables() As String

    Set vbPrj = VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Set codeMod = vbPrj.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
    code = codeMod.Lines(1, codeMod.CountOfLines)

    Set regex = New RegExp
    With regex
        .Global = True ' match all instances
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True ' "code" var contains multiple lines
        .Pattern = "(\sAs\s)([\w]*)(?=\s)" ' get list of datatypes we've used
            ' match any whole word after the word " As "
        Set matches = .Execute(code)
    End With

    ReDim datatypes(matches.count - 1)
    For i = 0 To matches.count - 1
        datatypes(i) = matches(i).SubMatches(1) ' return second submatch so we don't get the word " As " in our array
    Next i

    With regex
        .Pattern = "(\s)([^\.\s][\w]*)(?=\s\=)" ' list of variables
            ' begins with a space; next character is not a period (handles "with" assignments) or space; any alphanumeric character; repeat until... space
        Set matches = .Execute(code)
    End With

    ReDim variables(matches.count - 1)
    For i = 0 To matches.count - 1
    isInDatatypes = False
    isInVariables = False
        ' check to see if current match is a datatype
        For j = LBound(datatypes) To UBound(datatypes)
            If matches(i).SubMatches(1) = datatypes(j) Then
                isInDatatypes = True
                Exit For
            End If
            'Debug.Print matches(i).SubMatches(1)
        Next j
        ' check to see if we already have this variable
        For j = LBound(variables) To i
            If matches(i).SubMatches(1) = variables(j) Then
                isInVariables = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        ' add to variables array
        If Not isInDatatypes And Not isInVariables Then
            variables(i) = matches(i).SubMatches(1)
        End If
    Next i

    With regex
        .Pattern = "(\sConst\s)(.*)(?=\sAs\s)" 'strongly typed constants
            ' match anything between the words " Const " and " As "
        Set matches = .Execute(code)
    End With

    For i = 0 To matches.count - 1
        'add one slot to end of array
        j = UBound(variables) + 1
        ReDim Preserve variables(j)
        variables(j) = matches(i).SubMatches(1) ' again, return the second submatch
    Next i

    ' print variables to immediate window
    For i = LBound(variables) To UBound(variables)
        If variables(i) <> "" And variables(i) <> Chr(34) Then ' for the life of me I just can't get the regex to not match doublequotes
            Debug.Print variables(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Qbik I've updated my answer one last time. I just couldn't let it go until I figured it out. Give this a shot and please mark as accepted if this works for you.

Comment: It's been a long time since this question, I would now recommend anyone looking to replace identifier names to check out http://rubberduckvba.com/ instead.